# DNS lookup against PiHole fails for local hostnames on 20.04 (works on other systems)

Tags: systemd, dns, pi-hole

External DNS lookups work without issues, but anything for a non-FQ domain (i.e. only the hostname portion) fails unless I explicitly force it to use the PiHole to resolve it.

```
nslookup myhost # this fails with SERVFAIL
nslookup myhost 192.168.12.34 # this works
```

I'm confident the DNS entries are valid (added via the "Local DNS Records" interface on the PiHole) as they work from other systems on my network that aren't using systemd

`/etc/resolv.conf` is the systemd default (referring to 127.0.0.53) as I just did a fresh install two days ago.

`resolvectl status` shows the PiHole's IP as the sole DNS server for my wifi connection (the only active connection).

This is a fresh install of PopOS 20.04, and my PiHole was just updated to 5.0.

EDIT: To clarify, this host is *not* running PiHole - that's on another host on the network.

Anybody have any thoughts as to what's going on here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the simplest way to do this was just to bypass the loopback resolver by pointing the resolv.conf symlink to another file (which contains my PiHole's IP):

`sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

DNS does not recognize short names, i.e. host name only without additional information.

If you give nslookup a host name only, it will try to add whatever is configured as the search domain.  This is usually in /etc/resolv.conf like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search domain.com
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

If you do not have a search domain, or you are using the name of a host outside of the configured search domain, it will not resolve.

DNS needs a method to find the FQDN in order to resolve.

This is just my guess with the limited amount of information I have.